# Failing test with Spring WebFlux and Controller

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-webflux

I am tryng to write an unit test for a Spring Controller using Spring Webflux. The following is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    private Service service;

    public MyController (Service service) {
        this.service=service;
    }

    @GetMapping({"", "/", "/index"})
    public String createChain(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("blockchain", service.getString());

        return "index";
    }

}
```

This is the underlyng service interface:

```
public interface Service{

    Mono<String> getString();

}
```

And this is the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void getAString() {

        BDDMockito.given(service.getString()).willReturn(Mono.just("A string."));

        this.webTestClient.get().uri("/").exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();

    }
}
```

As you can see I'm simply trying to retrieve a string from a reactive service and I'm putting that string in and html template (I'm using Thymeleaf as template engine). However, I keep getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'index'.
>       at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$3(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:276) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoBufferAllSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:360) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:269) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:131) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2070) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1878) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1752) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:296) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:247) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2070) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:138) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:318) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3695) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:275) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:849) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2070) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1878) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1752) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3695) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:442) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:212) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3695) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3695) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:3801) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3689) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3656) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3628) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.lambda$connect$1(HttpHandlerConnector.java:89) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.mock.http.client.reactive.MockClientHttpRequest.lambda$null$2(MockClientHttpRequest.java:121) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3695) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable$ConcatIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatIterable.java:146) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable.subscribe(FluxConcatIterable.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements.subscribe(MonoIgnoreElements.java:37) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3695) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:3801) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3689) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3656) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3628) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.connect(HttpHandlerConnector.java:100) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WiretapConnector.connect(WiretapConnector.java:71) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:103) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebClient.java:319) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebTestClient.java:283) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at com.lorescianatico.driftcoin.controller.BlockChainControllerTest.createChain(BlockChainControllerTest.java:31) ~[test-classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]

I don't understand what's wrong. The template named `index.html` is located under `src/main/resources/templates/index.html`.

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Just tried, same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **WebFluxTest**: Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to WebFlux tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, and WebFluxConfigurer beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).
>
> If you are looking to load your full application configuration and use WebTestClient, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined with @AutoConfigureWebTestClient rather than this annotation.

[WebFluxTest Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/reactive/AutoConfigureWebTestClient.html)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void getAString() {

        BDDMockito.given(service.getString()).willReturn(Mono.just("A string."));

        this.webTestClient.get().uri("/").exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm not looking for a full application loading. I am trying to keep this test like an unit test as much it is possible.

Comment: your controller method returns a view, in that case view will try to get resolved which will not happen until auto configuration feature works. If you do not want full application loading, mock the controller and its methods.

Comment: Incase you are not doing integration test through ```WebTestClient```. All you need to is  ```@MockBean
    private MyController myController;

    @Test
    public void getAString() {

        BDDMockito.given(service.getString()).willReturn(Mono.just("A string."));
        Model model = Mockito.mock(Model.class);
        BDDMockito.given(myController.createChain(model)).willReturn("index");
       assertEquals("index", myController.createChain(model));

    }```